# Is there a pandas function to convert all the column heads against a particular header row into rows for that particular header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have a pandas dataframe like this where head wise amounts are available for all categories:

[Table depicting category wise head wise values where the heads are in the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHqum.png)

Now, I want a pandas function to return a dataframe like the image below where the head wise values will appear as rows for each category:

[Table where all the heads for a particular category appears as a separate row instead of column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M6gB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.melt()` to convert your dataframe from a wide to a long format where `'CATEGORY'` is your identifier variable, and elements under all of the other columns are values and get their own row.

```
new_df = df.melt(id_vars=['CATEGORY'], value_vars = ['ELCH_TOT','FXCH','FPA','ELDT','MTR_RENT','SOLAR_REBATE'])
```